# AUCTeX error 127

Tags: auctex, debugging, install

I'm trying to call AUCTeX from Emacs and I'm now getting the following error (quote marks changed slightly to get code block below to work):

```
Running 'TeX' on 'simple' with ''pdf/Users/myname/bin/pdflatex  -file-line-error   -interaction=nonstopmode  simple.tex''
/bin/sh: pdf/Users/myname/bin/pdflatex: No such file or directory

TeX Output exited abnormally with code 127 at Thu Jun  2 16:53:50
```

I've checked paths which seemed like they would be the problem, but couldn't find anything. I also executed `M-x shell` and entered

`pdflatex —version`

Which worked just fine, returning MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.10 (MiKTeX 22.1) …as well as plenty of normal looking copyrights and trademarks and compilation information.

So where do I go from here?

I’m running Emacs Version 28.1 (9.0) on a Mac mini M1 with macOS Monterey 12.4.

EDIT: As requested in the comments below, I've added that part of my .emacs file showing my attempt to set up AUCTeX:

```
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)

;; trying to get AUCTeX to work
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/Users/myname/bin"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/Users/myname/bin")))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/Library/TeX/texbin")))

(add-to-list 'exec-path "~/bin")
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/Library/TeX/texbin")
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/Library/TeX/texbin:"
                       (getenv "PATH")))
(setq TeX-command "/Users/myname/bin/pdflatex")
(setq LaTeX-command "latex")
```

Comment: Have you done any configuration of auctex in your init?  What is the value of the `LaTeX-command` variable?  It should be `latex` rather than a path.

Comment: @FranBurstall: Thanks for writing. I've added the relevant sections of my .emacs file to the original posting as an edit.

Comment: The value of `TeX-command` is wrong: it is supposed to be the command to run plain TeX and should be `tex` and not a path.  Remove this from yr config and try again.

Comment: @FranBurstall: It's working. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise the comments: this was a misconfiguration.  The documentation of `TeX-command` (do `C-h v TeX-command <RET>`) says:

> TeX-command is a variable defined in ‘tex.el’.
>
> Its value is "tex"
>
> Command to run plain TeX.

However the sexp,

```
(setq TeX-command "/Users/myname/bin/pdflatex")
```

sets it to be a path which causes `auctex` to construct a broken shell command to run TeX:

> pdf/Users/myname/bin/pdflatex  -file-line-error   -interaction=nonstopmode  simple.tex

Solution: delete that sexp!

Comment: Could you provide a link to that documentation? Google [can't find it](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22TeX-command+is+a+variable+defined+in%22).

Comment: I have edited the answer to remind you that emacs is self-documenting: no google required!